# writing to binary in Julia trying to get same output as Python struct.pack

Tags: python, binaryfiles, pack, julia

I'm trying to translate a python script into Julia and thankfully Julia has very been cooperative until this point….I need to get the same binary output writing to a file as with the python struct.pack function.

Strangely enough, when I examine the binary text files generated from each some of them look similar but have different sizes (while others are entirely disparate). When I examine these files in Hexdump, there are apparent differences. Is there a way to pass in specific data types (Char5, signedFloat, etc.) into Julia ala Python?
Here is my python code:

```
for item in RICQ.get("%s" %f)['Injury TIme']:    
   f3Q.write("%s" % struct.pack(signedFloat, item))
f3Q.close()
```

Here is my Julia code:

```
for x in RICQ["$i"]["Injury Time"]
    write(f2, x )
end
close(f2)
```

Comment: You can convert the values to the types you want and then write them to file. I don't know what a Char5 is or signedFloat, however, so I can't really help there.

Comment: how would one "convert the values"? I'm relatively certain that Char5 and signedFloat are python equivalents of generic C data types.

Comment: Neither `python Char5` nor `python signedFloat` yield anything in Google, so I don't think so. You can convert things to a type using the `convert` function. E.g. `convert(Float32,x)` will convert `x` to the `Float32` type.

Comment: `"%s" % struct.pack(...)`? That's just weird...`struct.pack` returns a string so you shouldn't need to stringize it.

Comment: `signedFloat` is going to be defined as a string somewhere else in the program (search for it). It's most likely defined as `'f'` or something similar, which is a 32-bit float type.

Comment: im hoping i see you guys for drinks later and we can poke fun at my diminutive programming skills in a way that encourages me to try harder next time and definitely not in a manner that compels me to listen to Sade, stop bathing, and call ex-girlfriends looking for reassurance. let's really hope its not the latter. thanks again.